# Implementing NotBoringActionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to implement [this](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar) library into my project. Due to lack of documentation, I'm not able to use this. I tried making a clone of it. I managed to download it, but failed to import as project since eclipse didn't detect it. Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: The help link was given in the project description itself - http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/11/20/making-your-action-bar-not-boring/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the guide on how to implement all clear in this [Blog](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/11/20/making-your-action-bar-not-boring/)